How can I implement open AI api. Do I need to use langchain or directly calling open ai api
I'm working on a project where I need to integrate AI on my website to recommend songs based on user input. For example, if a user says they want to listen to "sad songs" or "dance music," the AI should return some genres that match their input. Then, I need to find those genres in my database and return the songs related to those genres. I'm using a Node.js backend for this project.
Do you have any suggestions or advice on how to implement this? Specifically, I'm looking for recommendations on the best AI tools or libraries to use and any tips on integrating them with a Node.js backend.
I have tried calling open ai function but response I am getting is very large piece of text. I just need genres from AI. Also I am confused If I should use langchain or not. If yes what embedding should insert in vector database.
